# dynamically print column using column name using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file from which I m trying to print a column named as '**grant (actual)**' dynamically using the column name. I was able to derive the column by  iterating over column numbers using the below command and the current position  is column 6

```
$ awk '/--/,/Datacenter/ ' cas.txt  | awk '{print $6}'
(actual)
49.9%
55.4%
53.5%
48.7%

(actual)
53.1%
50.0%
47.6%
48.3%

(actual)
50.0%
51.1%
48.9%
51.3%
```

But I want to determine column number dynamically So that if there is a change in position of a column my script should work.

```
$ cat cas.txt
Datacenter: DC01
====================
Status=TRUE/FALSE
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       USER       grant (actual)      Host ID    Vol
DN  10.0.0.138  221.03 MiB  256          49.9%             dd09f7aa  STG1
DN  10.0.0.139  173.47 MiB  256          55.4%             53179492  STG1
DN  10.0.0.136  200.08 MiB  256          53.5%             89a28140  STG1
DN  10.0.0.137  318.69 MiB  256          48.7%             8cc9dfac  STG1
Datacenter: DC02
====================
Status=TRUE/FALSE
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       USER       grant (actual)       Host ID    Vol
DN  10.0.0.142  270.01 MiB  256          53.1%             04210b53  STG1
DN  10.0.0.143  166.65 MiB  256          50.0%             d5469c9b STG1
DN  10.0.0.140  199.51 MiB  256          47.6%             fcc38a17  STG1
DN  10.0.0.141  170.52 MiB  256          48.3%             3d7b4e59  STG1
Datacenter: DC03
====================
Status=TRUE/FALSE
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       USER       grant (actual)       Host ID    Vol
DN  10.0.0.150  229.2 MiB  256           50.0%             0fa51a1a  STG1
DN  10.0.0.151  195.88 MiB  256          51.1%             e329ac17  STG1
DN  10.0.0.148  147.01 MiB  256          48.9%             c14bd7ae  STG1
DN  10.0.0.149  298.34 MiB  256          51.3%             6c73d2b5  STG1
```

Comment: What's your field separator? Tabs or multiple spaces?

Comment: Its multi-space I believe

Comment: Unless you have a table with real delimiters, you're going to have hard time changing columns, due to whitespace, eg in the Load column. You might be better off with something like `grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]%'` to list percentages. Or maybe use 2 or more spaces to delimit, if no columns are only one space apart (`-F ' {2,}'`). Either method isn't very robust. If you have a delimiter, you can iterate over field numbers, checking for `$i == "grant"`, and `$i` will be your column.

Comment: do the lines of interest *always* start with `DN`?

Comment: Dn is not fixed. it can have other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for `FIELDWIDTHS` and the 4th arg to `split()` you can create an array (`f[]` below) that maps the column names to their numbers and then you can just print, compare, reorder or do whatever else you like with the columns just by indexing that array with the column names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^--/ {
    if ( FIELDWIDTHS == "" ) {
        wids = ""
        numFlds = split($0,flds,/  +/,seps)
        for ( fldNr=1; fldNr<=numFlds; fldNr++ ) {
            f[flds[fldNr]] = fldNr
            wids = (fldNr>1 ? wids " " : "") length(flds[fldNr] seps[fldNr])
        }
        FIELDWIDTHS = wids
        $0 = $0
    }
    inBlock = 1
}
inBlock {
    if ( /^Datacenter:/ ) {
        print ""
        inBlock = 0
        next
    }
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"",$i)
    }
    print $(f["grant (actual)"])
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk cas.txt
grant (actual)
49.9%
55.4%
53.5%
48.7%

grant (actual)
53.1%
50.0%
47.6%
48.3%

grant (actual)
50.0%
51.1%
48.9%
51.3%
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining @Dan's and @Daweo's ideas

```bash
awk -F' {2,}' -v col='grant (actual)' '
  /^Datacenter/ {i=0}
  $1 == "--" {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == col) break; next}
  i {print $i}
' cas.txt
```

```
49.9%
55.4%
53.5%
48.7%
53.1%
50.0%
47.6%
48.3%
50.0%
51.1%
48.9%
51.3%
```

If you want to see the col header in the output, just remove `next`

Answer (score 0):

Consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
-- Able Baker Charlie
DN 1    2     3
DN 4    5     6
DN 7    8     9
-- Charlie
DN 10
DN 11
DN 12
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{colname="Charlie"}/--/{delete names;for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){names[$i]=i};next}{print $(names[colname])}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
3
6
9
10
11
12
```

Explanation: I use `colname` variable for storing desired column name. When line containting -- is encountered it is treated as header with column names. `names` array is purged, to prevent having remnants from previous block, then filled so for name of column (key) correspond to its' position (value). After doing that I instruct GNU `AWK` to process `next` line, i.e. nothing is printed. For other lines I inform GNU `AWK` to find number corresponding to selected name and `print` that column.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: I have mentioned the content of file cas.txt. could you please use that as an example

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data we'll use `split()` to split record at 2 or more spaces (`/  +/`):

```
$ awk '$1~/^--$/ {                  # -- starts the header record
    n=split($0,h,/  +/)             # get field count n of header record
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)               # iterate fields 
        if(h[i]=="grant (actual)")  # looking for desired header
            break                   # break once found, i is the field number
}
split($0,a,/  +/)==n {              # process records with equal amount of fields
    print a[i]                      # and output ith field
}' file
```

Output:

```
grant (actual)
49.9%
55.4%
53.5%
48.7%
grant (actual)
53.1%
47.6%
48.3%
grant (actual)
50.0%
51.1%
48.9%
51.3%
```

Above fails for that one record where the last field is separated by only 1 space:

```
DN  10.0.0.143  166.65 MiB  256          50.0%             d5469c9b STG1
```

Answer (score 0):

**SYNOPSIS**

An `awk`-based solution that :

```
- doesn't require gnu-gawk for FIELDWIDTHS/fixed width fields

- doesn't require fudging with FS/OFS/RS/FPAT

- doesn't require a specialized regex engine, 

                  e.g. with back-references support

- doesn't require array-splitting or dealing with the 
                  painfully slow match() function

- doesn't *even* require a single call to any function
```

**INPUT**

```
Datacenter: DC01
====================
Status=TRUE/FALSE
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       USER       grant (actual)      Host ID    Vol
DN  10.0.0.138  221.03 MiB  256          49.9%             dd09f7aa  STG1
DN  10.0.0.139  173.47 MiB  256          55.4%             53179492  STG1
DN  10.0.0.136  200.08 MiB  256          53.5%             89a28140  STG1
DN  10.0.0.137  318.69 MiB  256          48.7%             8cc9dfac  STG1
Datacenter: DC02
====================
Status=TRUE/FALSE
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       USER       grant (actual)       Host ID    Vol
DN  10.0.0.142  270.01 MiB  256          53.1%             04210b53  STG1
DN  10.0.0.143  166.65 MiB  256          50.0%             d5469c9b STG1
DN  10.0.0.140  199.51 MiB  256          47.6%             fcc38a17  STG1
DN  10.0.0.141  170.52 MiB  256          48.3%             3d7b4e59  STG1
Datacenter: DC03
====================
Status=TRUE/FALSE
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       USER       grant (actual)       Host ID    Vol
DN  10.0.0.150  229.2 MiB  256           50.0%             0fa51a1a  STG1
DN  10.0.0.151  195.88 MiB  256          51.1%             e329ac17  STG1
DN  10.0.0.148  147.01 MiB  256          48.9%             c14bd7ae  STG1
DN  10.0.0.149  298.34 MiB  256          51.3%             6c73d2b5  STG1
```

**CODE**

```
< cas.txt |

{m,g}awk '   !NF   ? !_ : /^[=]+/ ? ($!_=!__ ? "" : " ") \
         : --NF<+_ ? !_ : __+=($!_=(/%/?"":$(_-_^!_)" ")($_))^!_' \_=6
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 1  grant (actual)
 2  49.9%
 3  55.4%
 4  53.5%
 5  48.7%
 6   
 7  grant (actual)
 8  53.1%
 9  50.0%
10  47.6%
11  48.3%
12   
13  grant (actual)
14  50.0%
15  51.1%
16  48.9%
17  51.3%
```

Comment: can you explain =6 at the end of line

Comment: just for $6, cuz there's where the grant actual % are at. i tried straight up NF decrementing but ran into the space pitfall at header row. but personally i already didn't like my own code for having to hard-code in a "6" - usually i like mine to dynamically generate the needed constants on the fly